# Input a number with degree

Tags: c, input, numbers

Help with problem: I need to write  C + + program, which input  and displays numeric variables with operators `printf` and `scanf`. the values are:

```
E = 10 ^ 3
 F = -450
 H = 0,005 * 10 ^ 2
 X = -43,562 * 10 ^ (-3)
 I = 75600
 Y = -0,00036
```

But I do not  understand how I have to enter `10 ^ 3` and other... at the moment my code is ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
    int E;
    int F;
    puts("Введите значения E и F");
    scanf("%d,%d", &E,&F);
    printf("Значение E=%2d\n",E);
    printf("Значение F=%4d\n",F);
    puts("-----------------------------");
    float H;
    float X;
    int I;
    float y;
    puts("Введите значение  I");
    puts("Введите значение H, X, Y");



    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You code at the moment is C, not C++. Please decide what tag to use

Comment: I removed the homework tag because it has been deprecated. Please see the community bulletin.

Comment: You need to input those values from the console and you don't know how? That's the question? You should use scientific notation. See this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/scientific/.

Comment: Please note that 10 ^ 3 in the C language means 10 bitwise XOR 3. You need to use the pow() function in math.h or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the answer is: use scientific notation

`10 ^ 3` becomes `1e3`,
`0.005 * 10 ^ 2` becomes `0.005e-2`
and so on